# PHP array's: How can i filter on an argument

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a huge JSON-string with +/-300 items. A shortened example:

```
[
{"DateGps":"2016-03-25T19:28:19+01:00","DateReceived":"2016-03-25T19:28:20.163+01:00","Longitude":5.85294,"Latitude":51.84475,"Speed":55,"VehicleNumber":"678","TravelNumber":"4321"},
{"DateGps":"2016-03-25T19:28:13+01:00","DateReceived":"2016-03-25T19:28:14.065+01:00","Longitude":4.8139,"Latitude":52.43844,"Speed":23,"VehicleNumber":"2335","TravelNumber":"1234"}
]
```

With

```
$array = json_decode($json,true); // i will convert this into a array.
```

But how can i get only the row where VehicleNumber the same is as VehicleNumber 2335?

Comment: There is a function `array_filter()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `array_filter` like as

```
$array = json_decode($json,true);
$resulted_array = array_filter($array,function($v){ return ($v['VehicleNumber'] == 2335);});
print_r($resulted_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same as [Uchiha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36259942/4833), but using an [anonymous class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) as a [FilterIterator](http://docs.php.net/filteriterator).
In this scenario it only adds (unnecessary) complexity (esp since json_decode(,true) returns an array and therefore the whole data is in memory anyway). But if you have a large amount of data *and* you can receive it step by step, iterators and/or [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) might come in handy ;-)

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(data(), true);
$it = new class(new ArrayIterator($data)) extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() { return '2335'==$this->current()['VehicleNumber']; }
};

foreach($it as $v) {
    var_export($v);
}

function data() {
    return <<< eoj
[
{"DateGps":"2016-03-25T19:28:19+01:00","DateReceived":"2016-03-25T19:28:20.163+01:00","Longitude":5.85294,"Latitude":51.84475,"Speed":55,"VehicleNumber":"678","TravelNumber":"4321"},
{"DateGps":"2016-03-25T19:28:13+01:00","DateReceived":"2016-03-25T19:28:14.065+01:00","Longitude":4.8139,"Latitude":52.43844,"Speed":23,"VehicleNumber":"2335","TravelNumber":"1234"}
]
eoj;
}
```